# what is the word/phrase when you are in a new place and cannot sleep?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There is a word/phrase which explains why we don't get sleep when we are in a new place. AFAIK it is/was due to the fact that our hunterer-gatherer ancestors were prey and at times when they moved they didn't know that the new place is secure or  not. Does anybody know a word/phrase which describes it rather than going through the whole wordy description ?

Comment: Huh. I don't experience this. I wonder how widespread it is.

Comment: http://edition.cnn.com/2016/04/21/health/poor-sleep-while-traveling/index.html

Comment: there is no commonly used idiom for this in my experience.  US english speaker.

Comment: If it's because you're in a different timezone, the best word is "jet lag". If it's just because it's a new and strange place, I know what you mean, but I can't immediately think of a phrase to capture it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't been hunter-gatherers for a very long time, but some people do suffer from insomnia when they travel.  Long hours on the road or rapid long-distance trans-meridian travel on high-speed airplanes can prevent many a traveller from getting a good night’s sleep. That's what we call **"travel-induced insomnia".**

> - Travellers going long distances on jet planes have to readjust their sleeping hours in a new place. Presidents and Prime Ministers take injections of sleep-inducing drugs to overcome [**travel-induced insomnia**](http://www.streetdirectory.com/etoday/drugs-used-for-overcoming-sleeplessness-ewafla.html) and to readjust to new working hours when travelling abroad.

Comment: did you read the link I share, it does talk about something called the first-night effect but even yours could be the thing.

Comment: the term is "jet lag".

Comment: ok. but *nobody* says "travel-induced insomnia", ever.

Comment: We're good. the OP now has options!

Answer (score 0):

Usually people just say, "I didn't sleep well because I wasn't in my own bed" or "I don't sleep well in a strange bed."